# hibernate exception when executing stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using Hibenate 3 jar files and trying to execute a stored procedure as

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "callStoredPrcoc",  
resultClass = ProcResult.class,  
query = "{call storedProc(?,:inputParam)}",  
callable = true,
readOnly=true
)
```

and getting below exception. Is this error possibly caused by the version of the Jar files or something else? Has anyone got thsi error any inputs will help.

```
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Oracle9Dialect.java:309)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1586)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1722)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
[3/29/12 16:30:20:915 CDT] 0000003f SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
```

Comment: Can you add your DB version, Hibernate version and JDBC driver that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQl Query to call Stored Procedure

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
        "CALL storedProc(:Parameter)")
        .addEntity(Stock.class)
        .setParameter("Parameter Name", "value");
```